# overlap images in the center of viewport - what semantic ui component to use

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I need to display some images (then animated with the transition module) in the center of  the page/vieport

What does `semantic-ui` component to use as container of this images? the containar should be always in the center overlapping all the other contents and adjust its size to the device (responsive)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Consider editing your question then to include your efforts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Segment. It would be great for your needs since it already has css class center aligned

```
<div class="ui center aligned segment">
  Center
</div>
```